# Manually place the ticks on x-axis, at the beginning, middle and end - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to always place the ticks on x-axis of Matplotlib always at the beginning, middle and end of the axis instead of Matplotlib automatically placing them?For example, I have a plot shown below.
[matplotlib plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3l0S.png)
Is there a way to always place 25 at the very beginning, 80  in the middle and 95 at the very end?
This is the code I tried in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def box(ax_position, percentile_values, label, label_position):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))
    ax1 = fig.add_axes(ax_position)
    ax1.set_xticks(percentile_values)
    ax1.tick_params(axis="x",direction="out", pad=-15, colors='b')
    ax1.set_yticks([])
    ax1.text(*label_position, label, size=8)
    plt.show()

box((0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1), (25,80,95),  "CA",(0.01, 1.3))
```

The number of values passed in percentile_values will always be 3 and these 3 always needs to be placed at the beginning, middle, and end - but Matplotlib automatically places these ticks as per the numerical value. This is what I am looking for:
[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LITzB.png)

I tried using matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator, but that does not help me though I can display only 3 ticks, but the position of the ticks is chosen by Matplotlib and not placed at the beginning, middle and end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the `set_xticks()` to have only the number of entries - (0,1,2) and use `set_xticklables()` to give the text you want to display - (25,80,95). Note that I have used numpy's `linspace` to get the list of numbers based on length of `percentile_value`. Also, I have removed the `pad=-15` as you have indicated that you want the numbers **below** the ticks. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def box(ax_position, percentile_values, label, label_position):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 2))
    ax1 = fig.add_axes(ax_position)    
    ax1.set_xticks(np.linspace(0,len(percentile_values)-1,len(percentile_values)))
    ax1.set_xticklabels(percentile_values)
    ax1.tick_params(axis="x",direction="out", colors='b')
    ax1.set_yticks([])
    ax1.text(*label_position, label, size=8)
    plt.show()

box((0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1), (25,80,95),  "CA",(0.01, 1.3))
```

[image]